# how can I remove left and right margin from my default.aspx

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio-2019

how can I remove the left and right margin from my default.aspx. I have tried to change the bootstap.cs but in vain. I am using just a standard template from the visual studio webapplication having standard default.aspx. But the problem that lot of space is left on the right side for the menu and for the page as well. The picture shows the required result.
Code is for site.master is below. I have just pasted but again it is standard in the visual studio. So the same reference can be taken.

[image: The desired result shown in picture]

```css
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" title="more options">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Application name</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Hello</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make a utility class or just directly add the following class to the elements.

> Add this inside your `Head` tag

```
<style>
.rm-margin{
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important; 
}
</style>
```

`!important` would override any bootstrap stylings.

> Add the `rm-margin` to the div you want

You can just change below lines

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top rm-margin">

<div class="container body-content rm-margin ">
```

Comment: Dear not working the code you provided. Since its default template from visual studio for webapplication project, so the change might be from somewhere in site.master or may be bootstrap.cs. I tried to change many parameters but that application and text are not moving left.

Comment: may i know where u added the code?

Comment: <style>.rm-margin{ margin-left: 0 !important; margin-right: 0 !important; 
} </stlye>
</head><body> <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
                    </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    </button>
                    <a class="rm-margin" runat="server" href="~/">Application name</a>
                </div>
                <div class="rm-margin">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

Comment: Cant paste all code but above you find the code it is pasted in site.master file.

Comment: I have updated the answer can you please check

Comment: Dear Done, No change at all.

Comment: Great Content is moved to right, only remaining the application part

Comment: cool. now just add `rm-margin` class to the div under `navbar `.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246700/discussion-between-aza01-and-darkforest).